# How do I debug an ejabberd crash report?

Tags: ejabberd

I am new to ejabberd, I compiled and ran the server but get this error during startup. The log is not very helpful but maybe someone knows how to parse it better than me. Any insight would e great.

```
    =CRASH REPORT==== 17-May-2011::16:30:19 ===
      crasher:
        initial call: application_master:init/4
        pid: <0.39.0>
        registered_name: []
        exception exit: {bad_return,
                            {{ejabberd_app,start,[normal,[]]},
                             {stringprep,nameprep,exmpp_not_started,"localhost"}}}
          in function  application_master:init/4
        ancestors: [<0.38.0>]
        messages: []
        links: [<0.38.0>,<0.40.0>,<0.6.0>]
        dictionary: []
        trap_exit: true
        status: running
        heap_size: 610
        stack_size: 24
        reductions: 132
      neighbours:

    =INFO REPORT==== 17-May-2011::16:30:19 ===
        application: ejabberd
        exited: {bad_return,{{ejabberd_app,start,[normal,[]]},
                             {stringprep,nameprep,exmpp_not_started,"localhost"}}}
        type: temporary
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Erlang Crashdump Viewer](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/crashdump_viewer.html) is (slightly) better than the raw dump file. You can start it up from the console: `erl -s crashdump_viewer`, then open your browser to http://localhost:8888/ and click on CrashDumpViewer at the top of the page.

Looking at your dump though, it looks like the exmpp application didn't get started. If you compiled from source, there are dependencies that you may have needed for exmpp. What do you see if you try `exmpp:start().` from the `erl` console?

Comment: Exmpp seems to be fine.
exmpp:start().
ok

What file should I be loading into the crash dump viewer?
It does not like the complete log or the crash entry I copied into the question. It just says:

An error occured:
crash is not an Erlang crash dump

Comment: There should be a erl_crash.dump file in your ejabberd log dir. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using an older version of erlang I updated to R14B02 (erts-5.8.3) and everything was fine.

Comment: R14B04 has the same problem